# Pytube connection error even when i'm connected

Tags: python-3.x, pytube

I've written the following script to download mp4 videos from youtube using pytube API:

```
from pytube import YouTube
import sys 


SAVE_PATH = input('Enter a saving path: ') 
LINK = input('Enter the link of the video: ')

try:
    yt = YouTube(LINK)
except:
    print('Connection error') 

print(yt.title)
items = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).all()
stream = items[0]

stream.download()
```

When i run the code i get the following error :

```
Connection error                                                                          
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                          
File "C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Python\youtube.py", line 24, in <module>                        
  print(yt.title)                                                                       
NameError: name 'yt' is not defined
```

What's the problem and how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the `video-link` you are giving to the program, if video-link is not proper or internet connection is not proper the `yt` will not be initialized and when it is not initialized you can't use it.

1. Try using a predefined link without taking input from user such as

   `LINK= #any youtube-video link`
2. If your program fails after giving a predefined link then your internet connection is not proper.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `yt = pytube.YouTube(LINK)`

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer to this question is that every mention to "yt" variable should be into the "try" block